# Create Series object with maxima from other Series objects

Tags: python, pandas, numpy

Assuming that I have three Series objects with the same length and containing float64 elements how to create another Series object (also with the same length) which will contain maximum values from those three Series? Is there a nifty way (instead of just writing for loop and comparing each three elements and append each maximum to collection) to do it in numpy?

Comment: Are you looking for np.max([s1,s2,s3], axis = 0)?

Comment: That's what I'm looking for. Thank you

Answer (score 2):

You can use the [nanmax](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy-1.13.0/reference/generated/numpy.nanmax.html#numpy.nanmax) method :

```
s1 = [1,3,4]
s2 = [1,4,6]
s3 = [np.nan,5,3]

np.nanmax([s1,s2,s3], axis = 0)
[out]: array([ 1.,  5.,  6.])
```

`nanmax` is safer over `max` since it handles `NaN` values

Comment: Yes. I had NaN's in my Series. That's useful.